# Compositing layers after blender restart

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, node-editor, compositing-nodes

In relation to the frequent error at rendering (cuda out of memory), after rendering every layer I must restart computer (it is helping to free memory on the card - when I am rendering layers directly after oneself, an error is taking place). Unfortunately when I am rendering one layer, automatically I am losing second one. In what way I can connect them unnecessarily for rendering both suddenly?

I have GeForce GTX 970, blender 2.77
[image]

Render layers with transparency and combine them in Photoshop can be some solution, but it is really problematic with more frames (animation).